# Why does Java runtime differ so much in how SSL trust store works and how do we deal with it?

Tags: java, ssl, jvm, truststore

We happen to run a REST API web service that exposes both http:// and https:// endpoints. The https:// endpoint has an SSL certificate behind it which needs to be updated once in a while. Every other time we update the SSL certificate some user running a Java program interfacing with our service complaints that his program no longer works and he has to change something in the Java certificate trust store. We have users with programs developed in anything - PHP, C#, Ruby, whatever else - and none of them ever complain when we change the certificate yet some Java users have problems every other time.

How is Java runtime special in this regard? What should we do to improve user experience?

Comment: Who is the issuer of the certificate?

Comment: Do you know what endpoints the "other" users are accessing?  If they are accessing `http` then changing the cert won't matter.

Comment: Updated how? If your certificate is signed by a recognized CA you should never have a problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Some major certificate companies like GoDaddy.

Comment: @EJP We run our service on Azure. We deploy new service instances with the new certificate, direct the incoming requests to them and then remove the instances with the old certificate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen We have plenty of users accessing `https://` endpoint who use stuff other than Java.

Comment: Oh, good, someone voted to close this as unclear! What exactly is unclear?

Comment: @sharptooth its strange, never happened for us. we use java to access https API. we however, don't use any special package for REST API specifically (if there is any). maybe you can ask your client what packages they are using.

Comment: This [article about GoDaddy certificates and Java](http://tozny.com/blog/godaddys-ssl-certs-dont-work-in-java-the-right-solution/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We have users with programs developed in anything - PHP, C#, Ruby, whatever else - and none of them ever complain when we change the certificate yet some Java users have problems every other time.

- PHP: until recently PHP did not verify certificates by default at all. This was only [changed with PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php). If it verifies it uses the system CA store on UNIX which has usually the CA needed. Thus it might be that your PHP clients simply don't verify the certificate and thus don't have problems.
- C# - uses the systems CA store which usually has the CA's needed
- Ruby: uses the system CA store
- Perl: either does not verify at all, uses the systems CA store or uses the CA store from mozilla, depending on the versions of the modules and on the distribution you use.

Java instead comes with its own CA store which includes far less CA then is usually shipped with the systems. And it also depends on the Java version. Thus it might be that the root CA you use is not known by the Java version the client uses. Also, older Java versions don't do SNI. And they have problems with weak DH keys, don't support larger keys for RSA etc. Since there are lots of old and unsupported Java installations out there pick the problem which affects your application today.

Comment: That's sad. Will user experience be improved if we announce certificate change in advance? How do REST API services typically deal with that large list of potential problems observed by Java users?

Comment: @sharptooth: I recommend that you specify minimal requirements for your API and then make sure that it all works within the minimal requirements before you make any reconfiguration of the production system (which includes new certificates). Since you provide no details what exactly went wrong in the past please expect no specific details on what you can do better.

Comment: Minimal requirements for a REST API? Can I see an example of those?

Comment: As far as I know, recent Java versions (at least the latest Java 8r60) has `CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US` (with `SHA256withRSA`) in its default trust store. In general, Java 8 has had many improvements regarding SSL/TLS too.

Comment: @sharptooth: minimal requirements like: the root CA, signature algorithm, TLS version and ciphers the client must support to successfully connect to your system. And then it would be nice if you could tell the client which versions of which programming language fit these requirements out of the box and which changes are needed to let the other clients connect to.

Comment: Is that an industry practice? Does anyone do this?

Comment: @sharptooth: a short look at facebook and google shows that they provide SDKs for various languages and not only describe a Rest API. And if you have a look for example [at this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java) or [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python) you see that they state the requirements to use these SDK. The SDK itself then can deal with such things as CA certificates etc so these don't need to be specified as separate requirements.

Comment: SDK is good however the point of REST API is that anyone can interface with it using just spare parts from their runtime so we'll still have Java users who have lower runtime version that we require for an SDK and who will have problems with the trust store.

Comment: @sharptooth: then you should at least detail the requirements of your API. Obviously it needs more than just a HTTP client but specific ciphers, protocol version, root CA. If you make these requirements clear your users can at least check against the requirements if they get problems instead of just trying to guess what went wrong this time. Apart from that it makes testing easier for yourself since you can restrict the tests to what you required.

Comment: Is there a good example of how these requirements are typically specified?

Comment: @sharptooth: No I don't have one except for the links I've already put in the comments. You might start with what you use for testing yourself, since that is what you can support :)